# Run external background service with intent

Tags: android, android-intent

Currently I have a blank service, which will eventually be used to determine if a licence has been purchased, this service is in an external app which its only job is to check, and verify the licence (external app: com.example.myapp.licence, main app: com.example.myapp)

com.example.myapp.licence > LicenceService.java:

```
public class LicenceService extends Service {

   @Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
      return null;
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {

   }

   @Override
   public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {

   }
}
```

com.example.myapp.licence > AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.myapp.licence"
      android:sharedUserId="com.example.myapp"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".My3DroidPaidLicenceActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".LicenceService" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

but this service force-closes when called with the following from within my main app...

com.example.myapp > MainActivity.java:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClassName("com.example.myapp.licence", "com.example.myapp.licence.LicenceService");

    List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

    if (list.size() > 0) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Can anyone please suggest why this is?

(my apologies if i have not explained anything very well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
    List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

if (list.size() > 0) {
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

with

```
startService( intent );
```

Comment: how silly of me -_-  thanks a lot (: am i right in thinking that now the entire process will now be done in the background (not freezing up the main app)?? or will i have to create a Thread within the service to prevent the main app locking up?

Comment: Correct. You don't need another thread in the service. The service will not run in the UI thread.

Comment: @IncrediApp, that is wrong!
'Caution: A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process—the service does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate process'